# How to complete Mothership Assault singleplayer mission?

Tags: unreal-tournament-2004

I'm playing on Skilled difficulty level. Completed 3 ladders and now trying to end the Assault one, but failed it twice.
Then I've collected some of the best bots into my team: Lauren, Brock, Thorax and Cobalt. Set them all on Auto-assign. They already, I believe, are much better in the ground fight, than I am. So I started the third try and both teams ran out of time on the second part of last task. Even while the first task (*destroy lower smth*) I did on the first life, in several seconds, it was still hard to land into the ship. And I tried my best and even scoreboard shows I did the game:

[image: scoreboard]
...but still weird system judged it as fail. So I could just try it again and again, but don't want to waste time on luck. I want to know the best tactics on this map.

Do you have any hints on specific tasks?

Comment: Man I hated playing that on single player.  It seemed no matter what bots you acquired, they were never able to hold their ground and you have to do most of the work.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some things you have to do on this assault map:

1. Make sure they spawn and work together.  Often, when you put them all on a task, such as auto-assign, they'll end up being stringed out where they die/spawn at different rates, in effect fighting 4-5 vs 1 most of the match.  Having said that, I don't think its possible to tell the bots to hold position in the space map *while they are in space*, so you'll either have to die, then tell them to hold position before entering the spaceships, so multiple numbers of you spawn at the same time, or just set them to attack mode and then do the work yourself.
2. I remember this map in particular, skimming the surface of the station helps a lot when you are trying to approach the entry point to land your vehicles.  I usually just order my bots to go on all out offensive in the space stage to distract the other ships while I hugged the surface of the station as much as I could.  Just watch out for the turrets (remember you can destroy them).  Also, you can fly through the center of the station from one side to the other to get at the points you need to destroy from within.  Most of the time you'll be left alone except for a few turrets guarding those points when you do this.
3. Even after entering the station, you have a ways to go, having to attack multiple points guarded by turrets.  I've found that the glob gun helps out a lot here, a fully loaded glob can one shot a turret, or at least take it down a lot.  There are a lot of tight spaces, so be careful going crazy with the rockets.  (You should be saving those for the final room where you have to destroy the core anyway).

The reason why it counts your side as a loss is probably because the other side progressed more into the assault than you did.